# AVPlayer(ViewController): can not play HLS HD video

Tags: ios, swift, wowza, http-live-streaming, avkit

I want to play an HLS stream using AVPlayer (in Swift).

This HLS stream plays in Safari, but not when I want to use AVPlayer.

My code:

```
let hlsLink = 'http://thelinktomyHLSmovie'
let player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: hlsLink)!)

let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
playerVC.player = player
presentViewController(playerVC, animated: true) {
    playerVC.player?.play()
}
```

If I do a CURL to the HLS URL to find out what kind of streams are in it, I get:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2328000,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720
chunklist_w1751887550_b2328000.m3u8?smil=1
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=128000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
chunklist_w1751887550_b128000_ao.m3u8?smil=1
```

Which seems OK to me.

If I do the same with some other streams that are smaller and shorter, everything works OK.

I already tried observing the status of the AVPlayer and the AVPlayerItem, but that did not report anything useful.

What am I missing?

**Update:**

I added a AVPlayerItem, as I already said. I also added a notification observer to the player, player view controller and player item for all notifications and `print`ed the output. This gave me the following:

```
Optional(NSConcreteNotification 0x7fd272bcd600 {name = AVPlayerItemTimebaseChangedNotification; object = <AVPlayerItem: 0x7fd2714f6c40, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x7fd27144e720, URL = http://hls.streamonecloud.net/vod/amlst:pwlsaeYN1ZuH/playlist.m3u8?smil=1>>})
Optional(NSConcreteNotification 0x7fd272bccaf0 {name = AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification; object = <AVPlayerItem: 0x7fd2714f6c40, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x7fd27144e720, URL = http://hls.streamonecloud.net/vod/amlst:pwlsaeYN1ZuH/playlist.m3u8?smil=1>>})
Optional(NSConcreteNotification 0x7fd272bcd710 {name = AVPlayerCurrentItemDidChangeNotification; object = <AVPlayer: 0x7fd27157ca60>; userInfo = {
    CurrentDuration =     {
        epoch = 0;
        flags = 17;
        timescale = 0;
        value = 0;
    };
    ReasonForCurrentItemDidChange = ReasonAdvanceAtEnd;
}})
Optional(NSConcreteNotification 0x7fd271759950 {name = AVPlayerItemTimebaseChangedNotification; object = <AVPlayerItem: 0x7fd2714f6c40, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x7fd27144e720, URL = http://hls.streamonecloud.net/vod/amlst:pwlsaeYN1ZuH/playlist.m3u8?smil=1>>})
```

I also inspected the `accessLog()` and `errorLog()` of the item. The access log contains no entries (but does exist) and the error log is nil.

I'm not sure anymore what to do. My log above contains the URL I want to load if anymore is interested (just Big Buck Bunny on one of our servers).

Comment: If you log the contents of the `AVPlayerItem`'s accessLog and errorLog, do they show anything useful?

Comment: Are you retaining player or simply instantiating it inside some method and invoking play to it ? Also, if you want to be able to stream videos you should use AVPlayerItem, otherwise it wont work

Comment: @PhillipMills I will log it and see what happens

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne I did retain both the player and the view controller (although not shown in my example). I also tried using an AVPlayerItem and even an AVAsset. Both didn't work

Comment: I am playing a HLS VIDEO from Dropbox.com. To get the video to play I needed to download it, at least start the process it seems with a switch at the end of my URL.